# when upload file with curl it show me curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration

i write this command in pipline for upload site in server .

```
sh 'curl -T /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Angular-CI-CD--Test_develop/dist/ang-CICD ftp://XXXXX:XXXX@XXXXXXXX/public_html'
```

but it show me this error :

```
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553

script returned exit code 25
```

i write this command in local folder :

`ls -ld /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Angular-CI-CD--Test_develop/dist/ang-CICD`

> drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Mar  9 12:42 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Angular-CI-CD--Test_develop/dist/ang-CICD

**how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 0):

There could be one of the below reasons for the failure :

1. I can see that the file you are trying to upload is actually a directory instead of file. You can run the below loop to upload all the files within directory one by one :

   ```
   sh """for file in /main/folder1/path/*
   do
   curl -u Pass:"Uname" -T  $file http://www.example.com/folder/$file
   done
   ```

   """
2. The server requires authentication for uploading. You can try running the curl with username & password like :
   sh 'curl -u "user:pwd" -T /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Angular-CI-CD--Test_develop/dist/ang-CICD ftp://XXXXX:XXXX@XXXXXXXX/public_html'
3. The 553 error code is coming directly from the remote FTP server. The file name is not allowed. Many FTP servers have restrictions on file names. If your file name contains special characters, symbols, or spaces in the file name, it might be rejected by the remote FTP server